# Cannot style anything with CSS anymore

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a simple rock paper scissors game, but my css isn't being applied. Here is my code:

(Header included outside of snippet)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
...
</html>
```

```css
#gameDiv {
  font-family: 'Brush Script MT', 'cursive';
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="gameDiv">
    <h1 class="gametext" id="playertext">Player :</h1>
    <h1 class="gametext" id="comptext">Computer :</h1>
    <h1 class="gametext" id="resulttext">Result :</h1>

    <button class="choosebuttons" id="rock">Rock✊</button>
    <button class="choosebuttons" id="paper">Paper✋</button>
    <button class="choosebuttons" id="scissors">Scissors✌️</button>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also wanted to note that this is my first question and i'm a new programmer, so sorry if this is stupid

Comment: Hey, I modified your HTML + CSS snippet to be runnable, and it _seems_ to be working here. It seems like there may be some additional context missing that's the root cause of the issue. Is there anything else at all on this page that might be impacting this? Such as an external css library, some js, or something else?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J, check your browser console for 404 Not Found errors for `styles.css`

Comment: @CollinD i do have some js, but i don't think it's breaking the website.

Comment: @LionelRowe i tried and did not find anything.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example so we can help you out. Maybe a link to a new github repo if you need several files to show the issue. With just this information, the best anyone can do here is essentially random guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F5, sometimes clearing the cache helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the href in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` and make sure your styles.css is actually where it is meant to be. right now your saying it should in the root folder or the same folder where your html file is. If your css in another folder you need to go that folder by setting href to ./folder/styles.css or if your html is another folder you need to get out of that folder by setting href to ../styles.css